# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on alert view object I retained, used, and then released

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I know this is a common problem, so I need an explanation so I don't keep having this problem. In my header file, I have defined a UIAlertView and retained it as shown:

```
@interface myController {
    UIAlertView *alert;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *alert;
```

In my implementation, I use and reuse this alert as follows:

```
@synthesize alert;

 ...

    if (self.alert != nil) {
        [self.alert release];
    }

    self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                       message:message
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Ok To Send", nil];

    [self.alert show];
```

I also release this in my dealloc.

So, I've heard the golden rule on memory management, but I apparently don't understand it. The golden rule says that you must never release an object that you have not either retained or obtained via alloc. You must always eventually release an object that you have either retained or obtained via alloc.

I retained it in the header file, so I eventually must release it in the dealloc. In my implementation, I perform an alloc of the alert object more than once, so each time I get ready to re-alloc it, I release the old one.

Please help me understand what I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@property` with `retain` specified is implemented something like this...

```
-(void)setAlert:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
        if (self->alert != alert)
        {
                [self->alert release];
                self->alert = [alert retain];
        }
}
```

So by assigning a new value to the property, the property will handle the `release` of the previous value... so when you manually `release` it, you're over-releasing.

Also, since you have the `@property` set to `retain`, you should `autorelease` before assigning to the property:

```
self.alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                         message:message
                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  
                               otherButtonTitles: @"Ok To Send", nil] autorelease];

[self.alert show];
```

Comment: awesome. Thank you so much for that explanation. I've been haunted by it over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Your property retains. So when you set with self.* it retains for you. Similarly when you set the property to nil or another object it release the old property object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are double-retaining your alert!
self.alert does a retain, your object has already retainCount of 1 since it's been instantiated with alloc init

Try this:

```
//if (self.alert != nil) {
//    [self.alert release];
//}

self.alert = nil;

alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                   message:message
                                  delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Ok To Send", nil];

[self.alert show];
```

instead!

Comment: In my humble opinion this is a "classic" case in which you don't need a property (unless you need to access the alert from another class...)

Comment: Or be the alertView delegate, which in fairness I don't think he is either since I see no protocols listed.